# Change Cisco VPN User Password Question

Tags: cisco, vpn, cisco-ios

I have telnetted into a Cisco 2851 Router with 7 set users with passwords for a PPTP VPN that show in the following format when I "show running-config":

username user1 privilege 0 password 7 84HF7CJ384NF83JF2T

How would I go about keeping this user but simply changing the user's password?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command in config mode:

```
username user1 privilege 0 password NewPasswordForUser
```

That will change their password to `NewPasswordForUser`

EDIT: I should mention that it is recommended to use `secret` instead of `password` for increased security on the device. i.e.:

```
username user1 privilege 0 secret NewPasswordForUser
```

Though you can't switch from password to secret without removing the user or you'll get this error:

> ERROR: Can not have both a user password and a user secret.

To make the change you'll want to remove the user:

```
no username user1
```

Then readd with a `secret` instead:

```
username user1 privilege 0 secret NewPasswordForUser
```

Comment: I added some info about moving to using the `secret` argument instead of `password`.

Comment: Note: type 7 passwords are not "encrypted" (it's trivially reversible.) Any mechanism that needs to process a plaintext password (which is possible with PPTP, i.e. CHAP) won't work with a non-type 7 (or plaintext) password.